# how to get package name from a class file?

Tags: java, bcel

I want to get package name from a .class file, but after trying to use `org.apache.bcel`, I am not satisfied with it because there are always some classes which can not be parsed.

the rate is about 20 over 500.

So, is there any other library which can get the package name from a class file?

Edit:
this is how I get a package name from a class file now.
This can achieve my goal, but some class files can not be parsed, so I want to know is there a better way.

```
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;

        String filePath = "/tmp/Test.class"
        ClassParser classParser = new ClassParser(filePath);

        JavaClass javaClass;
        try {
            javaClass = classParser.parse();
        } catch (IOException | ClassFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }

        String packageName = javaClass.getPackageName();
```

Comment: Are you parsing actual .class files or `MyObject.class` using reflection

Comment: In Java or how do you want to get the package name? What are you doing right now? Show the code please. [`getPackage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage()) of a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object should return the [`Package`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html). Calling [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getName--) on it return the name.

Comment: @Mark I am parsing actual .class files

Comment: @AKSW I have some class files, I want to filter them by package name. the class files are not written by me and I have no source code.

Comment: well, but you have to load the class files then, or not? can you show the code that you'Re running now?

Comment: `Class.getPackage().getName()`?

Comment: @AKSW I have re-edit my question, I want to find a better way because this method sometimes failed.

Comment: Still, see my first comment. The methods are there, just get the `Class` object from the `JavaClass` object

Comment: @AKSW to do that, one would first have to load the class. If the class file does not reside in the class path, one would have to create a new `ClassLoader` for that. Still, that's all possible and probably worth a try.

Comment: @ohlec I know, I was just referring to the code snippet in the question. Indeed, I don't know for which classes and why the `org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser` fails. I never used this API. So yes, I don't have an answer here

Comment: @user3978288 to clarify: Are you talking about cases where `classParser.parse()` throws an exception? If so, which one (and with what message)?

Comment: @ohlec  Seems the bcel is platform dependent? I parse the same class files on my mac, got 20 exceptions out of 500 classes. But when I run the same code on linux, I got zero exception.

Comment: @user3978288 again: What exceptions are you getting, with what messages?

Comment: @ohlec . org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18